# How to find an Equivalent point in a Scaled down image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to calculate the corner points or contours of the star in this in a Larger image. For that I'm scaling down the size to a smaller one & I'm able to get this points clearly. Now How to map this point in original image? I'm using opencv c++.
[image]

Comment: yes u can if aspect ration is still the same. if x coordinate of P1 is X in smaller one, then on the larger one it will be X*(1024/640)

Comment: scaling is done with some origin. If the scale-origin is (0,0), you can just multiply each point with the scaling factor. If you want to scale around the other point, you'll have to compute `(point-scaleOrigin)*scale_factor + scaleOrigin` . If you want to scale them around the center of the star, you'll have to compute the center of gravitiy of the star and use that as your scaleOrigin. Mapping will be the inverse of this operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a trivial example: the image size is reduced exactly by half.

So, the cartesian coordinate (x, y) in the original image becomes coordinate (x/2, y/2) in the reduced image, and coordinate (x', y') in the reduced image corresponds to coordinate (x*2, y*2) in the original image.

Of course, fractional coordinates get typically rounded off, in a reduced scale image, so the exact mapping is only possible for even-numbered coordinates in this example's original image.

Generalizing this, if the image's width is scaled by a factor of `w` horizontally and `h` vertically, coordinate (x, y) becomes coordinate(x*w, y*h), rounded off. In the example I gave, both w and h are 1/2, or .5

You should be able to figure out the values of `w` and `h` yourself, and be able to map the coordinates trivially. Of course, due to rounding off, you will not be able to compute the exact coordinates in the original image.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question. I just wanted to add to Sam's answer above, to deal with "*rounding off*", in case other readers are wondering the same thing I faced.

This rounding off becomes obvious for even # of pixels across a coordinate axis. For instance, along a 1-D axis, a point demarcating the 2nd quartile gets mapped to an inaccurate value:

```
axis_prev = [0, 1, 2, 3]
axis_new = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

w_prev = len(axis_prev) # This is an axis of length 4
w_new = len(axis_new) # This is an axis of length 8

x_prev = 2
x_new = x_prev * w_new / w_prev

print(x_new)
>>> 4
### x_new should be 5
```

---

In Python, one strategy would be to linearly interpolate values from one axis resolution to another axis resolution. Say for the above, we wish to map a point from the smaller image to its corresponding point of the star in the larger image:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x_old = np.linspace(0, 640, 641)
x_new = np.linspace(0, 768, 769)

f = interp1d(x_old, x_new)

x = 35
x_prime = f(x)
```