# Cannot find position of a point when scaling down image in android

Tags: android, opencv, android-constraintlayout

I was trying to make an application that can find rectangles in an image and highlight the corners of the same. I was able to find the corners of the image using OpenCV and no issues with it. But when i try to place some object like a small imageview to show the corners, it does not get itself at the correct position. After some brainstorming i realised that the image would be scaled and so i have to position the markers accordingly.
I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684327/how-to-find-an-equivalent-point-in-a-scaled-down-image) answer and used that method and tried to calculate the constraints to locate the marker but still it is not accurate (not even a bit). Just as an example i am providing an image i captured.
[image: Captured image showing incorrect corners]
Here, the red circles are drawn by OpenCV (the required position) whereas the white-grey circles are those that were calculated.

Here is the code: (imgViewHeight and imgViewWidth are known constants)

```
protected void showCorners(List<Point> corners, Bitmap image){
        List<ImageView> markers = new ArrayList<>();
        markers.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c1));
        markers.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c2));
        markers.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c3));
        markers.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c4));

        ConstraintLayout cornerLayer = findViewById(R.id.cornerLayer);

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
            Point point = corners.get(i);

            //TODO: Correct the algorithm to find constraints.

            double constraintTop = ((imgViewHeight*point.y)/image.getHeight());   //Here are the problems
            double constraintLeft = ((imgViewWidth*point.x)/image.getWidth());    //Here are the problems

            Log.d("Constraints", constraintLeft+" x "+constraintTop);

            ImageView marker = markers.get(i);
            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            set.clone(cornerLayer);
            set.connect(marker.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, cornerLayer.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, (int)constraintLeft);
            set.connect(marker.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, cornerLayer.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, (int)constraintTop);
            set.applyTo(cornerLayer);
            cornerLayer.bringChildToFront(marker);

            marker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

Here is the part of my layout containig the `cornerLayer` (it is a constraintLayout):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cornerLayer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_view_edit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a_corner"
            android:src="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/cornerLayer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cornerLayer" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a_corner"
            android:src="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/cornerLayer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cornerLayer" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a_corner"
            android:src="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/cornerLayer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cornerLayer" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c4"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a_corner"
            android:src="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cornerLayer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cornerLayer" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have given some default constraint values just for showing neatness in android studio but it gets changed so it doesn't matter (i suppose).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would suggest you to use something like a scale function
a) your image
b) for your corner points

I wrote some python code which demonstrates how to scales
both:

```
import cv2
filename = 'rectangle.jpg'
#read and show image 
imageOriginal = cv2.imread(filename,1) 
cv2.imshow('origin',imageOriginal)

#def corners
corners = list()
corners.append((0,0))
corners.append((430,0))
corners.append((0,280))
corners.append((430,280))

#def intial scale factors
scaleFactorX = 2
scaleFactorY = 2
#create a img copy for scaling
imageScale = imageOriginal.copy() 

#def colours
blue = (255,0,0)
red = (0,0,255)

#b) function to scale points
def scalePoints(corners,sx,sy):
    cornersScaled = list()
    for c in corners:
         scaledPoint = ((int(c[0]*sx),int(c[1]*sy)))
         cornersScaled.append(scaledPoint)
    return cornersScaled

# we scale the image and draw scaled points
def scaleImageAndPoints(x,y):
    global imageOriginal 
    global corners
    global scaleFactorX
    global scaleFactorY 
    scaleFactorX = x 
    scaleFactorY = y  
    #scale image
    #a)
    imageScale = cv2.resize(imageOriginal, (0,0), fx=scaleFactorX, fy=scaleFactorY) 
    #we print corners origin in blue
    for c in corners:
         cv2.circle(imageScale, c, 10,blue,5)
    #we scale the points
    scaledCorner=scalePoints(corners,scaleFactorX,scaleFactorY)
    #we print corners scaled in red
    for c in scaledCorner:
         cv2.circle(imageScale, c, 10, red,5)
    cv2.imshow('scaled',imageScale)
    
# callback function for trackbars
def UpdateX(value):
    if value == 0: #we avoid trackbars zero 
    value = 1
    scaleImageAndPoints(value,scaleFactorY)
def UpdateY(value):
    if value == 0: #we avoid trackbars zero 
    value = 1
    scaleImageAndPoints(scaleFactorX,value)

#create window ,add trackbars, and show it
cv2.namedWindow('scaled',cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
cv2.createTrackbar("x scale factor", "scaled", 2, 10, UpdateX)
cv2.createTrackbar("y scale factor", "scaled", 2, 10, UpdateY)
#inital open
scaleImageAndPoints(scaleFactorX,scaleFactorY)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here a pic how the output looks like, the blue dots are the non-scaled points and the red dots are scaling with the picture:

[image: example]

and the example picture for reproducing:
[image]

The cpp functions will work analog. I hope to find time to code this example in cpp too..

Comment: hey friend, Firstly, I am using java with android so your code wouldn't work there.Secondly, Even if i try to transcode it into java, i wouldn't be able to succeed because my app should work for different screen resolutions and i cannot determine any scale factor for them because there is no standardisation in mobile devices. But still thanks for trying to help...

Comment: I think that i should repeat that i need to place android widgets at those points and i cannot draw them using opencv

Comment: ups.. i forgot about the java language option, but in general it would be the same idea, using cv.resize for the image and transform the corner points x,y with two scaling factor

Comment: Sorry friend, but it didn't help. The method that you used here, i.e, point's x * scalefactor is the same i am using but the results are coming incorrect. Maybe it's an android issue and there are no mistakes in the calculations. But thanks for trying...